# Access profile page by username or id

Tags: javascript, node.js, meteor, iron-router

I use the user system in Meteor. The accounting are created with an email but I want to give the users the option to set an unique username in their settings.

I have this route

```
Router.route('userProfile', {
  path: '/users/:userId',
  template: 'userProfile',
  fastRender: true,
  waitOn: function() {
    return Meteor.subscribe('singleUser', this.params.userId);
  },
  data: function() {
    return {
      user: Meteor.users.findOne(this.params.userId)
    };
  }
});
```

but if the user has set his/her username, the route path should be `path: '/:username',` instead. I think this is what Facebook, LinkedIn, etc. also does.

Answer (score 0):

Just pick up the single parameter and check it in your publication and data functions:

```
Meteor.publish('singleUser', function (userIdOrName) {
  return Meteor.users.find({ $or: [ { _id: userIdOrName }, { username: userIdOrName } ] }, {limit: 1});
});

Router.route('userProfile', {
  path: '/users/:userIdOrName',
  template: 'userProfile',
  fastRender: true,
  waitOn: function() {
    return Meteor.subscribe('singleUser', this.params.userIdOrName);
  },
  data: function() {
    return {
      user: Meteor.users.findOne({ $or: [ { _id: this.params.userIdOrName }, { username: this.params.userIdOrName } ] })
    };
  }
});
```

Note that in this case, you should make sure that a user cannot set another person's ID as his or her username, or else he/she could impersonate this person.